# Absolute positioned Div not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

This is the code that I trying

CSS

```
<style>
.myposition {
    position:absolute;bottom:0; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:30px;
}
</style>
```

Code

```
<td width="300" valign="top" style="position:relative;">
  <div style="top:0">
    <table width="310" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">content</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="myposition">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom">content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">content</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</td>
```

This code is working perfectly in IE as I want but not going well in all other browsers, the div with absolute positioning is overlapping the div above it.

What I am trying to make is this, please check
http://www.spoiledagent.com/ads/Help.jpg

You can check it at http://www.spoiledagent.com/members/about_hanu.php
I have given access to this link

Comment: We can't access the URL you gave us.

Comment: `code is working perfectly in IE`, _working perefctly_ is a subjective thing. What is your expectation with this code?

Comment: I have given access, please check this url now
http://www.spoiledagent.com/members/about_hanu.php

Comment: I am expecting the first content to be at top of the <td> with position relative and the last content to be at bottom of it, and the two content in between should adjust their margins automatically.

Comment: "This code is working perfectly in IE as I want but not going well in all other browsers" Well that should be your first clue that something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Stuff like `<td valign="top" align="center">` was deprecated ages ago. Use CSS.

Comment: The website has been designed long ago and now I cannot change the code, is there any way to fix this?
What I want is this 
http://www.spoiledagent.com/ads/Help.jpg

Comment: tables aghhhh.... you know... you can convert it to HTML & CSS like in 2013

Answer (score 2):

Gecko doesn't support table cells being absolute containing blocks.  That's on the one hand a bug in Gecko and on the other a lack in the spec (which explicitly says that the behavior of specifying `position: relative` on a table cell is not defined).